# How do I name a class variable based on the value of a different variable?

Tags: python-3.x

The code below is meant to take a list of files to read and name some class variables according to the names I give the files in the `attrs` list.

```py
class Test:   
    def __init__(self, file_names):
        attrs = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
        for i, f in enumerate(file_names):
            self.attrs[i] = np.loadtxt(fname=f)
            f.close()
```

When I make an instance of the class, I get the following error:

`AttributeError: Test instance has no attribute 'attrs'`

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Don't dynamically name variables based on the values of other variables. Not only is that not python best practices, that's against software engineering in general best practices. That will make your code a nightmare to debug and maintain in the future.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can see why this should not be done.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create the list first, which is easiest to do with a list comprehension.

```
def __init__(self, filenames):
    self.attrs = [np.loadtxt(fname=f) for f in filenames]
```

If you don't want a list comprehension, you start with an empty list and *append* to it. (Note that you create a local variable, not an instance attribute, with `attrs = [...]`.)

```
def __init__(self, filenames):
    self.attrs = []
    for f in filenames:
        self.attrs.append(np.loadtxt(fname=f))
```

(You could start with a preallocated list, e.g. `self.attrs = [None for f in filenames]`, and then your original loop would work. But there's little reason to do so.)

Comment: This is good for practical purposes, but I'm wondering if it is possible to give a class variable a name from another variable.

Comment: It is, but I'm not going to give it even the appearance of a recommendation by adding an example to the answer.

Comment: This question wasn't about dealing with lists. It was about naming class variables using the values of other variables.

Comment: And that's a terrible idea. Don't do it. You can replace the list with a `dict` if you like; the keys would be `f'file{i}'` in that case.